# How to (easily) be able to use a new en_** locale?

Tags: locale

I want to use an en_IL.UTF-8 locale - but I can't `locale-gen` it. I can choose this value in `/etc/default/locale` but that's apparently not enough for all apps. It seems like I need to get `locale-gen` to generate some files for en_IL.UTF-8 ... How do I do that? And what else do I need to setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generating a locale requires two files, a locale definition and a character map. In your case you'll need to create the former; you can probably adapt [`en_GB`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/en_GB) and [`he_IL`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/he_IL) to produce your own `en_IL` matching your requirements. The latter will just be the standard [`UTF-8`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/charmaps/UTF-8).

Once you have both files, run `localedef` to compile the locale; something like

```
mkdir en_IL.utf8
localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_IL en_IL.utf8/
```

That should produce `LC_ADDRESS`, `LC_COLLATE` etc. in the `en_IL.utf8` folder. You should copy that folder to `/usr/local/lib/locale`, so it ends up as `/usr/local/lib/locale/en_IL.utf8`. Once that's done,

```
LANG=en_IL.UTF-8 locale
```

should produce the expected output, and you can use your new locale.

Depending on your exact distribution you may need to add `en_IL.UTF-8` to `/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, or perhaps copy the folder to `/usr/lib/locale` instead of `/usr/local/lib/locale`.