# Create custom configuration for LC_NUMERIC

Tags: ubuntu, locale

I want to change system behaviour so it uses "." as decimal separator and "" as thousands separator. I have checked `LC_NUMERIC` options and none of them seem to offer me this behavior without modifying date formats too.

I wonder if there is any specific way to create a custom `LC_NUMERIC` format with a custom set up, something like:

```
decimal_point="."
thousands_sep=""
(...)
```

Comment: The recipe given [in this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209853/86440) should work for you — ignore the `he_IL` part and pick [the appropriate source file](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=localedata/locales). (Not suggesting a dupe since I have a hammer here.)

Comment: I downloaded the document, I changed the decimal_point part and try to reload it but I keep having the same behaviour as in the original document... I am using ubuntu 18 and perhaps I am copying it incorrectly?

Comment: Did you create a new locale, or try to update the existing one?

Comment: I downloaded the locale from that website and change just the part of "decimal_point", then I tried to load it in Ubuntu but I was probably placing it incorrectly because I didn't see any changes

Comment: What do you mean by “tried to load it in Ubuntu”? Where did you place the modified file, and what commands did you run?